# What is the chronological order for the Shakugan no Shana series?

Tags: shakugan-no-shana

I recently got all the Shakugan no Shana DVDs from Right Stuf (Shakugan no Shana Season 1 - 3, Shakugan no Shana S OVA and Shakugan no Shana The Movie). I am wondering what is the chronological order for the entire series?

Comment: Chronologically you should start with Shakugan no shana S, since it's stuff that happens before the first season

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Shakugan no Shana I
2. Shakugan no Shana II
3. Shakugan no Shana S (OVA)
4. Shakugan no Shana III (Final)

The Movie is a summary/alternate version of the first season.